# Understanding a small abstraction of openGL with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, buffer, lwjgl

The LWJGL API is not direct openGL calls, everywhere I look there is a small layer of abstraction, I guess that is why it's called light weight.

Much of the abstraction is similar, for example, code in this example is common throughout the source

```
public static void glBufferSubData(int target, long offset, FloatBuffer data) {
    ContextCapabilities caps = GLContext.getCapabilities();
    long function_pointer = caps.glBufferSubData;
    BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(function_pointer);
    BufferChecks.checkDirect(data);
    nglBufferSubData(target, offset, (data.remaining() << 2), MemoryUtil.getAddress(data), function_pointer);
}
```

As you can see, the LWJGL user would be calling this function, and then this function would call the real GL function. I assume the "n" in nglBufferSubData stands for native.

So my question is, what does this code mean? I have an idea what this function does, It submits a data into a openGL buffer object. I just don't understand the things that are happening in the code.  Could someone break it down for me?

Answer (score 4):

Some OpenGL functionality is available through the extensions. Different platforms support different extensions or even features of the OpenGL specification.

`ContextCapabilities` class knows about which features are supported.

`long function_pointer = caps.glBufferSubData;` gets the pointer to the native OpenGL method [glBufferSubData](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBufferSubData).

`BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(function_pointer);` checks if that pointer is not null, if null - feature is not supported and exception is thrown.

`BufferChecks.checkDirect(data);` ensures if a buffer [is direct](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) (and, implicitly, non-null).

`nglBufferSubData(target, offset, (data.remaining() << 2), MemoryUtil.getAddress(data), function_pointer);` Now we have proper data and a proper pointer to the [glBufferSubData](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBufferSubData) and here we invoke it with specified target, offset and size in bytes.

Comment: @Dan Webster, does this answer your question?